# .attr not defined d3js

Tags: d3.js, svg

I have a svg in which i wish to zoom and pan. 
I followed this example : http://bl.ocks.org/sgruhier/1d692762f8328a2c9957 using d3.js v3

I am implementing this in typescript as follows:

```
            this._svg = d3.select('body')
                .append('svg')
                .attr('style', 'max-width: 100%')
                .attr('viewBox', this._viewbox_x + ' ' + this._viewbox_y + ' ' + this.responsemodel.width + ' ' + this.responsemodel.height)
                .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on('zoom', this.zoom))
                .append('g')
```

and my zoom function

```
 zoom() {
    this._svg.attr('transform', 'translate(' + (<d3.ZoomEvent>d3.event).translate + ')scale(' + (<d3.ZoomEvent>d3.event).scale + ')');
}
```

When runnig this, I´m told "Cannot read property 'attr' of undefined" which comes from the fact that _svg is undefined.

[image]

Can someone explain to me why this is and how to solve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any chance of putting the complete code in a fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: yes. https://jsfiddle.net/a1L0jLj3/ 
But the problem does not appear here

Comment: You need to put all your TypeScript in the fiddle. You can change the language on the code input file by selecting the settings cog that currently says 'JavaScript' and changing this to TypeScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's because your `this` on your event callback refer to the `window` object.

Did you try to bind your `this` representing your chart to the event function as:

```
    this._svg = d3.select('body')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('style', 'max-width: 100%')
        .attr('viewBox', this._viewbox_x + ' ' + this._viewbox_y + ' ' + this.responsemodel.width + ' ' + this.responsemodel.height)
        .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on('zoom', this.zoom.bind(this)))
        .append('g')
```